# Declare field in class that extends multiple interfaces

Tags: java, querydsl

I'm working with QueryDSL and i'm trying to create something "general" to query all my entities, without write predicates for each of them.

Because I'm using JPA, I have interfaces that extends `JpaRepository`, and because I'm using QueryDSL the interface extends too `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`

The interface is something like this:

```
public interface MyUserRepository extends JpaRepository<MyUser, Long>, 
  QuerydslPredicateExecutor<MyUser> {
```

Now I have a generic service that have a field to access JPA repository:

```
private JpaRepository<E, ID> repository;
```

This works but I cant use the method `findAll` that is described in `QuerydslPredicateExecutor`.

So the question is, there is a syntax to change `private JpaRepository<E, ID> repository;` and say that `repository` extends `JpaRepository` and `QuerydslPredicateExecutor`.

More in general a syntax to say that a field extends multiple interfaces, so when I use it i can access to all methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could have added the generic type argument to your `MyUserRepository` interface.

```java
public interface MyUserRepository<E, ID>  extends JpaRepository<E, ID>, 
  QuerydslPredicateExecutor<ID>
```

Then you could declare your `repository` object as

```java
private MyUserRepository<E, ID> repository;
```